# In The Thing, who investigates the crash site?

Tags: character-identification, the-thing-1982

In the Thing (1982), three characters get in a chopper and examine the crash site. MacReady and Norris talk and are identifiable. Who is the third man? Is it Palmer?

[image: The thing 1982]

And continuity fans, both hoods of their coats are up in the next shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thing,-The.html) confirms that the three men are Macready, Norris **and Palmer**

> EXT. GLACIER - TRACKING WITH MACREADY, NORRIS AND PALMER
>
> as they walk along the ice. They come to a stop at the edge 
>                  of a sharp drop.
>
> Pull back to reveal -- the massive black hole about fifteen 
>                  feet beneath the ice. Charred, gnarled and mangled metal are 
>                  all that is left of what was once an enormous sphere.
>
> MacReady's and Norris' eyes meet each other in silence.